# build a binary classification model with LSTM

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, lstm, text-classification

I have a dataset in csv format with 49 columns, some of them are strings and some of them ar integers.

I have added a new column to use as label called "input" with appropriate label as 0 & 1.

Here's a sample of the dataset:
[image]

The requirement is to consider all of these feature columns for model training.

What options I have to train this model?
What steps should I follow?
Any resource(article, video etc) will be very appreciated.

Thank You,

Comment: Can you give more information of  about what have you tried?

Comment: why `LSTM` of all models?

Comment: @Andrei @shahaf `LSTM` is the requirement from client and the confusing part is the utilization of all the feature columns which includes string columns mostly with 1 or 2 words , should I implement a `tokenization`?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two tutorials that might help you:

https://towardsdatascience.com/machine-learning-recurrent-neural-networks-and-long-short-term-memory-lstm-python-keras-example-86001ceaaebc

https://stackabuse.com/time-series-analysis-with-lstm-using-pythons-keras-library/

This tutorial is about mixed data:
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/02/04/keras-multiple-inputs-and-mixed-data/

I would suggest trying Keras to familiarize yourself with how to train it, if you're not using something else that is not mentioned.

Just writing your question in google will help you find many specific tutorials!

**EDIT:**
From keras documentation:

```
keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=None, dtype='float32')
```

Converts a class vector (integers) to binary class matrix. E.g. for use with categorical_crossentropy.
Arguments

- y: class vector to be converted into a matrix (integers from 0 to num_classes).
- num_classes: total number of classes.
- dtype: The data type expected by the input, as a string (float32, float64, int32...)

Returns:

A binary matrix representation of the input. The classes axis is placed last.

```
# Consider an array of 5 labels out of a set of 3 classes {0, 1, 2}:
> labels
array([0, 2, 1, 2, 0])
# `to_categorical` converts this into a matrix with as many
# columns as there are classes. The number of rows
# stays the same.
> to_categorical(labels)
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: I was thinking about Keras, butt eh confusing part is that I have to utilized all the features and also LSTM but how can I convert columns with string to  tokenization? also thinking about `one-hot encoding`

Comment: What have you used now? Tensorflow? Something else?

Comment: I'm at the preprocessing stage, can use any one TF or Keras.

Comment: Strings are just categorical data so you can one-hot encode it.

Comment: The tutorial about mixed data will help you give all columns as input

Comment: If we have more than 2 categories for a column like `frequency` column has three values in unique as `['POPLATEK MESICNE' 'POPLATEK TYDNE' 'POPLATEK PO OBRATU']` can we apply `one-hot-encoding` to this?

Comment: Yes you can, it will for example code them as [0, 0, 1]; [0, 1, 0]; [1, 0, 0].